# Getting org.osgi.framework.AdminPermission check failed

Tags: components, osgi, osgi-bundle, wildfly-10, java-security

I am getting below exception after enabling security manager flag in wildfly can anyone help me here please how can i  avoid this ? I tried adding `<permission class="org.osgi.framework.AdminPermission" name="*" actions="*"/>` in standalone.xml but still getting same exception.

java.security.AccessControlException: WFSM000001: Permission check failed (permission "("org.osgi.framework.AdminPermission" "(id=0)" "context")" in code source "(vfs:/content/myapp.war/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge_1.2.100.v20120209-2014.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this question from JBossDeveloper forum , there is already same question is in discussion for reference please refer:
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/275647